# Cómo obtener los últimos 5 minutos de registros en una consulta Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CP.IDCONTAINER,ORDC.ORDERNUMBER, CP.IDITEM, CP.QUANTITY, CONT.IDLOCATION, PL.LOCATIONNAME, CP.LASTUPDATEDATE AS FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, SYSDATE
FROM CPD_OP_CONTAINERS CONT
LEFT JOIN CPD_OP_CONTAINERPRODUCTS CP ON CONT.IDWAREHOUSE = CP.IDWAREHOUSE
LEFT JOIN CPD_OP_ORDERCONTAINERS ORDC ON CONT.IDWAREHOUSE = ORDC.IDWAREHOUSE
LEFT JOIN CPD_CTLG_PHYSICALLOCATIONS PL ON CONT.IDLOCATION = PL.IDLOCATION
WHERE CONT.IDWAREHOUSE = :IDWAREHOUSE
AND ORDC.ORDERNUMBER = :ORDERNUMBER
AND CONT.STATUS = 4
AND CP.IDITEM = :IDITEM
AND CP.QUANTITY = :QUANTITY
AND CONT.IDLOCATION = :IDLOCATION
AND CONT.IDCONTAINER = ORDC.IDCONTAINER
AND SYSDATE > (SYSDATE - (5/(24*60)))
ORDER BY CP.LASTUPDATEDATE DESC;
```

De la cual quiero obtener los registros de hace 5 minutos, pero me muestra varios de fechas pasadas.
Adjunto una imagen con prueba de la fecha de hoy:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna validación que me falte revisar, o algo mal en la definición de la consulta?

Comment: ¿Estás queriendo comparar la fecha del sistema contra la fecha del sistema? ¿O estás queriendo comparar la fecha del sistema contra `CP.LASTUPDATEDATE`?

Comment: En CP.LASTUPDATEDATE se graba la fecha y hora de acción, la cual con respecto a SYSDATE es una diferencia de segundos o talvez fracción, lo veía indiferente de cual utilizar ya que donde estoy disparando esta consulta es una sección de dos instrucciones más abajo que la que graba a LASTUPDATEDATE.

Comment: Buscas  los registros de hace 5 minutos  de la tabla CP.LASTUPDATEDATE en relación a la hora actual del sistema ?

Comment: Exactamente, ya que si se compara de acuerdo al campo CP.LASTUPDATEDATE si se visualizará porque siempre habría uno antes que el actual, y la idea es revisar con respecto a la fecha y hora actual.

Comment: A lo que iba es que en una de tus cláusulas tenés `AND SYSDATE > (SYSDATE - (5/(24*60)))`, y que en realidad quisiste escribir `AND SYSDATE > (CP.LASTUPDATEDATE - (5/(24*60)))` (o la columna que corresponda).

Answer (score 1):

Como no tengo la estructura de todas las tablas que relacionas, cree una única tabla con la estructura del dataset que esta en la imagen que publicaste, y sobre ese se aplicaron los cálculos.

Adicionalmente se filtran registros para solo devolver los registros que coinciden con la fecha actual.

```
CREATE TABLE CPD_OP_CONTAINERS 
( 
    IDCONTAINER NUMBER, 
    ORDERNUMBER NUMBER, 
    IDITEM NUMBER, 
    QUANTITY NUMBER, 
    IDLOCATION NUMBER, 
    LOCATIONNAME VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    SYS_DATE DATE
)
```

```
INSERT INTO CPD_OP_CONTAINERS
            (IDCONTAINER,ORDERNUMBER,IDITEM,QUANTITY,IDLOCATION,LOCATIONNAME,FECHA_RECORDPRODUC,SYS_DATE  )
SELECT      IDCONTAINER 
           ,ORDERNUMBER 
           ,IDITEM 
           ,QUANTITY 
           ,IDLOCATION
           ,LOCATIONNAME    
           ,TO_CHAR (TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS FF9') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')B
           ,SYS_DATE           
FROM
    (
                   SELECT 1022112700083     IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'15/02/21 13:58:01.383424000' FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21' SYS_DATE  FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700082    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTOL9' LOCATIONNAME,'15/02/21 13:57:13.681956000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700081    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'09/02/21 17:30:33.911491000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700064    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO1Y' LOCATIONNAME,'11/11/20 15:13:16.753920000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700062    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 15:28:46.134502000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700060    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 14:40:09.123687000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 110221253000057   IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 11:10:02.903213000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700061    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTOL9' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 11:06:04.645337000' FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'   SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 110221253000051   IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTOL9' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 11:05:44.389322000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 110221253000045   IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 11:03:40.092661000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700059    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO1Y' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:30:11.192441000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700058    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:29:09.273698000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700057    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:26:34.401570000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700056    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:25:28.479531000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700085    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTOL9' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:24:29.550168000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700054    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:23:40.627472000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700053    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19Y'LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:22:56.822729000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
        UNION  ALL SELECT 10221129700094    IDCONTAINER,19524905 ORDERNUMBER, 230728 IDITEM,  10 QUANTITY, 229 IDLOCATION, 'PTO19' LOCATIONNAME,'10/11/20 10:21:53.720468000'  FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, '13/02/21'  SYS_DATE     FROM DUAL
    )t
```

```
SELECT       IDCONTAINER,ORDERNUMBER,IDITEM,QUANTITY ,IDLOCATION,LOCATIONNAME,FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT,DIFF_MINS            
FROM (    
        SELECT
                 IDCONTAINER,ORDERNUMBER,IDITEM,QUANTITY,IDLOCATION,LOCATIONNAME,FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT,TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                ,EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )MINS
                ,EXTRACT( DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )DAYS
                ,EXTRACT( MONTH FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )MONTHS
                ,EXTRACT( YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )YEARS
                ,EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )SYS_MINS
                ,EXTRACT( DAY FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( to_char( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )SYS_DAYS
                ,EXTRACT( MONTH FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( to_char( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )SYS_MONTHS
                ,EXTRACT( YEAR FROM TO_TIMESTAMP( to_char( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )SYS_YEARS
                ,EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM 
                           ( TO_TIMESTAMP( to_char( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                             -        
                             TO_TIMESTAMP( FECHA_RECORDPRODUCT, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
                            ) DIFF_MINS
                ,SYS_DATE 
    FROM CPD_OP_CONTAINERS
) t
WHERE DAYS = SYS_DAYS AND MONTHS = SYS_MONTHS AND YEARS = SYS_YEARS
AND DIFF_MINS <= 5
```